# Applying Holder Inequality to obtain a estimate.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, holder-inequality

I'm reading a paper concerned with PDE, a inequality in it makes me confuse.
We have known:
$$\int|\nabla u|^{p-2}|A|^2\eta^2\leq C\int|\nabla u|^{p}$$
and author says we can obtain following inequality by applying Holder inequality:
$$\int|\nabla u|^{p-2}|A|\eta^2\leq C\left(\int|\nabla u|^{p}\right)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}$$
in which $p\geq 2$.
I believe that to applying the first inequality, we need all of three terms square, but that can't achieve the form we want. Any hint are very welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Both inequalities are a bit suspicious since they have different scaling in $u$ on both sides (in the first, the power is $p-2$ on left side and $p$ on right side). Inequalities need to scale in the same way on both sides. What is $A$? I assume $\eta$ is a cutoff function?

Comment: Tes, the $\eta$ is a cut-off. The $|A|$ is a function concerned with $\nabla u$ which we needn't to worry because we just need use first inequality to obtain ${\nabla u}^{p}$, the first estimate has been established before and nothing about the problem. The problem only concern with choosing suitable exponent to obtain the second inequality, but I failed to choose the exponent.

Comment: are you sure the powers are right? which paper is it btw?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I have found the correct exponent, it's

$$\int|\nabla u|^{p-2}|A|\eta^2\leq\left(\int|\nabla u|^{p-2}|A|^2\eta^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int|\nabla u|^{p}\right)^{\frac{p-1}{p}-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int\eta^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq C(\int|\nabla u|^{p})^{\frac{p-1}{p}}$$

I will shut down the problem, thanks for comments.